# Entity persists even when form has error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an issue where I have a form type that persists the associated entity even when the form is not valid.
I have confirmed that the form indeed has errors via $form->getErrorsAsString(). I have also confirmed that the logical if statement that checks if the form is valid or not comes out false. The entity still persists despite the fact that the form is never valid.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I have no other spot that I can find that either persists the entity or flushes the entity manager. Here's my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/settings/profile", name="settings_profile")
 * @Template();
 */
public function profileAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $profile = $user->getUserProfile();

    if (null === $profile) {
        $profile = new UserProfile();
        $profile->setUser($user);
        $profileDataModel = $profile;
    } else {
        $profileDataModel = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->find('MyAppBundle:UserProfile',$profile->getId());
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(),$profileDataModel);
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // This logic never gets executed!
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $profile = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($profile);
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->setFlash('profile_saved', 'Your profile was saved.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('settings_profile'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form'      =>  $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: `$em->persist($profile); $em->flush();` are responsable for persisting object so, it isn't possibile that your code "skip" `isValid()` control. Can you use a logger for make sure of what you're claiming

Comment: You form is simply valid then. Maybe you have to define validation constraints.

Comment: Are you saying that because your form is pre-filled after the first submit ?

Comment: Edited to clarify -- I am positive the form is not valid, even $form->isValid() returns false. The entity still persists though.

Comment: Do you have any form type subscribers? Try to insert "echo "passed"; exit;" inside "if ($form->isValid()) {" statement and submit the form. Also update Symfony to the recent version.

Comment: Yeah, I did try the echo test and was able to verify that is the valid path never executed (the `echo "passed";`). I don't have any form type subscribers that I know about.

Comment: Do you have any data transformers or other listeners on the form that may be calling ->flush()?

Comment: I must have something somewhere. I'm just not sure where I would have something that would call ->flush() on the logged in user object on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have a listener or something somewhere that is persisting the user.

My work around for this temporarily is to do:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // persist
} else {
    $em->clear();
}
```

Until I can ferret out what listener or other data transformer is causing this.

Comment: or do $em->refresh($profile);  That reloads the original data.

Comment: And hang your own listener on the entity manager and grab the preFlush event.  That will verify that flush is indeed getting called somewhere.